# Add model to list of another model

Tags: c#

Model:

```
public class DataModel1
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DataModel2
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add DataModel1 to DataModel2 as code below.

```
List<DataModel2> dataModel2List = new List<DataModel2>();
dataModel2List.Add(db.DataModel1.Select(row => row).FirstOrDefault()); // The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DataModel2>.Add(DataModel2)' has some invalid arguments.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the `DataModel1` to a `DataModel2` as you have a type mismatch.

```
dataModel2List.Add(db.DataModel1.Select(row => new DataModel2() 
{
    Id = row.Id,
    Name = row.Name
}).FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly assign `DataModel1` to a collection of `DataModel2`.

You need to modify your Select-Query like:

```
dataModel2List.Add(db.DataModel1.Select(row => new DataModel2
            {
                Id = row.Id,
                Name = row.Name,
                Phone = "???"
            }).FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution is to define constructor in datamodel2 to intialize values from datamodel1

```
public class DataModel2
{
   Public DataModel2()
   {
   }
   Public DataModel2(DataModel1 model1)
   {
      Id= model1.Id;
      Name = model1.Name;
   }
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Now the adding part

```
 List<DataModel2> dataModel2List = new List<DataModel2>();
 dataModel2List.Add(new DataModel2(db.DataModel1.Select(row => row).FirstOrDefault()));
```

You can remove the default constructor or use it of your application can use it.

Hope this may help